# Sporadic ConnectFailure to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have set up an Amazon S3 bucket to manage images/files.  Our web application running on IIS 7.x at different times has to use Amazon S3 API/SDK to pull a document from the bucket.  It works most of the time however sporadically (a few times a day) our requests for documents fail.

The following is the exception message:

```
System.Exception: An error occurred here with the message 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.218.144.25:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse()
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

We have increased RAM/CPU but we continue to get sporadic failures.  We have increased the retries and timeouts (10minutes) but are still seeing these exceptions/failures.

Have others seen this issue/resolution?

thx

Comment: Are your EC2 instances calling to S3 inside public subnets (with direct internet access), or in private subnets (connection through a NAT) ?

Comment: Direct internet access I believe.

Comment: @David Have you attached IAM role while launching an EC2 instance ?

Comment: I am not using ec2, just accessing the s2 bucket via .net s2 sdk/api

Comment: We are seeing this too, it seems tied to the number of S3 requests being made in a given period, I think there are some request limits to S3 that can cause this issue.  If you ever figured it out, please let me know!